# On[Event] Hooks for Google Apps Scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm looking specifically to see if there is an `OnExport` hook for Google Sheets, but this begs the question of if there is an `On[Event]` hooks for any document types (Docs, Sheets, Slides) in Google Apps Scripts.
I'm trying to error check before the Sheet is exported to CSV.

Any help would be appreciated, but I don't see anything in the [Apps Scripts Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets) or [API Documentation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api)

Comment: See https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers

Comment: "I'm trying to error check before the Sheet is exported to CSV" Please explain the workflow you are doing. Perhaps you may want to use the [Drive Activity API](https://developers.google.com/drive/activity/v2)

Comment: I will be exporting these files for download directly, nothing uploaded to Drive @Aerials

Comment: Thank you @Rubén I [found the triggers here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events) but alas there is no OnExport method

Comment: I have submitted a [Feature Request](https://issuetracker.google.com/186142724) to Google for this